# Combination of Map and Integration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is the equation that I'm trying to plot, but have not been successful for hours. XA is variable between 0 to 1. I'd like to plot it while I'm varying eA and n constants. I'm still learning Python and this is being too complicated for me. Any help will be very appreciable.

[image]

```
XA = np.linspace(1e-2, 1-1e-2, 20)

from scipy.integrate import quad
def integrand(XA):
    return ((1+eA*XA)/(1-XA))**n

p = lambda XA: quad(integrand, 1e-2, XA)[0]

xs = 1-XA

def func(n, eA):
    return (XA*((1+eA*XA)/(1-XA))**n)/(p)

n = [1, 1, 2, 2]
eA = [1, 2, 1, 2]

ys = list(map(func, alps, e))

plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the functions in order to use them in further calculations. Also make sure to supply the needed arguments to the functions.

Here would be an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

bracket = lambda eA,XA,n: ((1+eA*XA)/(1-XA))**n 

p = lambda eA,XA,n: quad(lambda x: bracket(eA,x,n), 1e-2, XA)[0]

func = lambda eA,XA,n: XA*bracket(eA,XA,n)/p(eA,XA,n)


ns = [1, 1, 2, 2]
eAs = [1, 2, 1, 2]
XAs = np.linspace(3e-2, 1-1e-2, 50)

for e,n in zip(eAs,ns):
    ys = list(map(lambda x: func(e,x,n), XAs))
    plt.plot(XAs, ys, label="n={}, $e_A$={}".format(n,e))

plt.xlabel("$X_A$")
plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnes, Thank you so much for your insight. This is what I was looking for. I appreciate your help.